# How to better select multiple rows with different attribute values in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a table with many rows.  Each row has an attribute called 'row_id'
I also have a query below that will get me the rows I am looking for.  While this works, I would really love to have a shorter way of writing this query.

```
var rows = jQuery("tr[row_id='apple'], tr[row_id='banana'], tr[row_id='cherry']");
```

Again, the above DOES work, but is there a way to write this with less code?  It would be great if I only had to write tr[row_id=' once ... instead of over and over again.

CLARIFICATION:  I will be looking for a different set of row_id's each time.  I will not be looking to get every table row that simply has the row_id attribute.

Comment: Are there other IDs you are _not_ selecting?

Comment: That's as simple as it gets. Do you have a real example that makes this seem worth it?

Comment: no.  I just need the rows that have the row_id's that I am looking for, and this list will be dynamic.  So, sometimes I will want apple and orange, and other times it could be apple, banana, and mango, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `filter` as well.

```
var rows = jQuery('tr[row_id]').filter(function(){
    return /apple|banana|cherry/i.test(this.getAttribute('row_id'));
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X6Y7u/)**

You can make it more generic this way as well:

```
var list= ["Apple", "banana", "cherry"]; //get the array of matches you need
var regexp = new RegExp("^(" + list.join('|') + ")$", "i"); //create the expression.


var rows = jQuery('tr[row_id]').filter(function(){
    return regexp.test(this.getAttribute('row_id')); //test it 
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FH9Mh/)**

or with the same thing make your selector on the fly:

```
var list= ["apple", "banana", "cherry"];
var selector = 'tr[row_id=' + list.join('], tr[row_id=') + ']';

var rows = jQuery(selector);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9Eeg7/)**

Comment: PSL, I gave this a try, works great.  One request:  row_id's with 'banana' and 'banana pie' will both be caught with a filter of apple|banana|cherry.  How can I make the filter match for exact text without worrying about case.

Comment: Ok, I ran your revised second fiddle, this gets me home, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This may work, but may be a lot slower. And it's not less code.

But it's easier to add all yout filters on a regex (you can just use an `Array.join()`);

```
jQuery("tr[row_id]").filter( function(i) {
    return /(apple|banana|cherry)/.test( $(this).attr("row_id") );
});
```